# hostapd 5GHZ a/n/ac mode

Tags: wifi

This is my Hostapd config file to configure mye 5GHz accespoint:

```
#bridge mode

bridge=br0
interface=wlan0
# the interface used by the AP
hw_mode=a
# a simply means 5GHz
channel=0
# the channel to use, 0 means the AP will search for the channel with the least interferences 
ieee80211d=1
# limit the frequencies used to those allowed in the country
country_code=BE
# the country code
ieee80211n=1
# 802.11n support
ieee80211ac=1
# 802.11ac support
wmm_enabled=1
# QoS support

ssid=raspberry         
# the name of the AP
auth_algs=1
# 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both
wpa=2
# WPA2 only
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=raspberry
```

this is the output when I start hostapd. I want to setup a 5Ghz acces point, but that doesn't work

```
pi@raspberrypi1:~ $ sudo hostapd -dd  /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=1
nl80211: Create interface iftype 6 (MONITOR)
Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Driver does not support monitor interface type - try to run without it
nl80211: Enable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x139b038
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x139b038 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=64): ret=-22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Failed to enable Probe Request frame reporting in AP mode
nl80211: QCA vendor test command returned -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 4
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 4
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 4 3
nl80211: Adding interface wlan0 into bridge br0
phy: phy0
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code BE, new country code BE 
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=BE (DFS-ETSI)
nl80211: 2402-2482 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5710 @ 160 MHz 27 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 57000-66000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=36 freq=5180 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=40 freq=5200 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=44 freq=5220 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=48 freq=5240 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
ACS: Automatic channel selection started, this may take a bit
ACS: Scanning 1 / 5
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
nl80211: Scan frequency 5180 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5200 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5220 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5240 MHz
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 10 seconds
wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ACS
wlan0: ACS-STARTED 
Interface initialization will be completed in a callback (ACS)
ctrl_iface not configured!
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 master=4 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 master=4 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 master=4 operstate=2 ifi_family=7 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Add ifindex 4 for bridge br0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 4
nl80211: ifindex 4 already in the list
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=br0 operstate=6 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
wlan0: Event INTERFACE_STATUS (5) received
Unknown event 5
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
Unknown event 47
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 5180 5200 5220 5240
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
ACS: Using survey based algorithm (acs_num_scans=5)
nl80211: Fetch survey data
wlan0: Event SURVEY (46) received
No survey data received
ACS: Scanning 2 / 5
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
nl80211: Scan frequency 5180 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5200 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5220 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5240 MHz
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
Unknown event 47
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 5180 5200 5220 5240
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
ACS: Using survey based algorithm (acs_num_scans=5)
nl80211: Fetch survey data
wlan0: Event SURVEY (46) received
No survey data received
ACS: Scanning 3 / 5
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
nl80211: Scan frequency 5180 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5200 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5220 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5240 MHz
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
Unknown event 47
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 5180 5200 5220 5240
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
ACS: Using survey based algorithm (acs_num_scans=5)
nl80211: Fetch survey data
wlan0: Event SURVEY (46) received
No survey data received
ACS: Scanning 4 / 5
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
nl80211: Scan frequency 5180 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5200 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5220 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5240 MHz
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
Unknown event 47
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 5180 5200 5220 5240
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
ACS: Using survey based algorithm (acs_num_scans=5)
nl80211: Fetch survey data
wlan0: Event SURVEY (46) received
No survey data received
ACS: Scanning 5 / 5
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
nl80211: Scan frequency 5180 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5200 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5220 MHz
nl80211: Scan frequency 5240 MHz
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlan0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
Unknown event 47
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 5180 5200 5220 5240
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
ACS: Using survey based algorithm (acs_num_scans=5)
nl80211: Fetch survey data
wlan0: Event SURVEY (46) received
No survey data received
ACS: Trying survey-based ACS
ACS: Unable to collect survey data
ACS: All study options have failed
Interface initialization failed
wlan0: interface state ACS->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
ACS: Possibly channel configuration is invalid, please report this along with your config file.
ACS: Failed to start
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
wlan0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> 0 (Success)
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_deinit_driver: driver=0xd8b84 drv_priv=0x139b328 -> hapd_deinit
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=3)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Teardown AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=1 use_monitor=1
hostapd_deinit_driver:bss[0]->drv_priv=0x139b328
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x1399cd8)
Interface wlan0 disabled
wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x1399cd8)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x1399cd8)
wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x139a9a0 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=0xd8b84 drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x1399cd8)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x139a9a0
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x1399cd8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x1399cd8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x1399cd8
```

---

edit: this js the output of sudo iw list

```
sudo iw list
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 10
    max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
    max # match sets: 16
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: 508
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1062
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x1062
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        VHT Capabilities (0x00001020):
            Max MPDU length: 3895
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            short GI (80 MHz)
            SU Beamformee
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: not supported
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: not supported
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5190 MHz [38] (disabled)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5210 MHz [42] (disabled)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5230 MHz [46] (disabled)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (disabled)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (disabled)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (disabled)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (disabled)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * join_ibss
         * set_pmksa
         * del_pmksa
         * flush_pmksa
         * remain_on_channel
         * frame
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * tdls_oper
         * start_sched_scan
         * start_p2p_device
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * crit_protocol_start
         * crit_protocol_stop
         * Unknown command (122)
    Supported TX frame types:
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 1
    Device supports scan flush.
```

Comment: `channel=0` - have you tried setting a channel instead ... as a test ... because it seems the "survey" data is "unavailable"

Answer (score 2):

As far as I read the debug log the driver attempted 5 times to get some 5GHz frequencies but ended with:

```
No survey data received
ACS: Trying survey-based ACS
ACS: Unable to collect survey data
ACS: All study options have failed
Interface initialization failed
wlan0: interface state ACS->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED
ACS: Possibly channel configuration is invalid, please report this along with your config file.
ACS: Failed to start
```

That looks for me that the 5GHz band isn't supported at all. What Raspberry Pi do you use? This feature is only supported by a Raspberry Pi 3A+ or 3B+. All other RasPis only support 2.4GHz. What frequencies are supported you can check with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iw list
```

You should find a section **Band 2:** with frequencies > 5GHz. If not then your RasPi isn't capable to support this Band.

Comment: `only supported by a Raspberry Pi 3B+` and the new 3A+ of course